# Trigger jquery function from select dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This should be really easy, but I have been going around in circles with it for the past three hours... I know that I should change the ID of SELECT to match that of the jquery function, but there is another step (obviously) that I am missing.

I am using the jqueryui datepicker, and I simply want it to pop up when a particular value is chosen with a 'select' dropdown, rather than when an 'input' field is clicked. Here is the code, thanks in advance for your help:

```
    <SELECT id="">
        <option value="1">TODAY</option>
        <option value="2">TOMORROW</option>
        <option selected value="3">THIS WEEK</option>
        <option value="4">NEXT WEEK</option>
        <option value="5">THIS MONTH</option>
        <option value="6">NEXT MONTH</option>
        <option value="7">CALENDAR SHOULD POP UP WHEN THIS OPTION IS SELECTED</option>
    </SELECT>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="INSTEAD OF THIS">

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      minDate: 0, maxDate: "+2Y"
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: The website in question is: http://www.s-on.ch

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can bind a change handler to the select element and trigger the [datepicker's show method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show) like:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 7) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("show")
  }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pyh572qr/1/)**

Comment: Wow, thanks a million! I guess that I will just now hide the #datepicker input onpageload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do things like this. A `switch()` will help identify what to do when specific options are selected in the drop down, and they can then tell the `.datepicker()` what to do.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+2Y"
  }).hide();
  $("#select-date").change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "7") {
      $("#datepicker").show().datepicker("show");
    } else {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("hide").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<SELECT id="select-date">
  <option value="1">TODAY</option>
  <option value="2">TOMORROW</option>
  <option selected value="3">THIS WEEK</option>
  <option value="4">NEXT WEEK</option>
  <option value="5">THIS MONTH</option>
  <option value="6">NEXT MONTH</option>
  <option value="7">CALENDAR</option>
</SELECT>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Now you can also do this with a ComboBox or Split Button if you were interested. To fit with the site more, you may consider:

```js
$(function() {
  var $datepick = $("#datepicker"),
    $opt7 = $("#select-date option[value='7']");
  $datepick.datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    onSelect: function(sDate, dObj) {
      $opt7.html(sDate);
      $datepick.hide();
    }
  }).hide();
  $opt7.click(function(e) {
    $datepick.show().position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "right top",
      of: $("#select-date")
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<SELECT id="select-date">
      <option value="1">TODAY</option>
      <option value="2">TOMORROW</option>
      <option selected value="3">THIS WEEK</option>
      <option value="4">NEXT WEEK</option>
      <option value="5">THIS MONTH</option>
      <option value="6">NEXT MONTH</option>
      <option value="7">CHOOSE DATE</option>
    </SELECT>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```